# update merge query with where clause in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

note: i m importing data from sql sheet. and after this i want to insert data in a table but when it finds same ContractNo (contract number) it will update the data and when it finds different ContractNo ( contract number) it will insert as a new record

but my merge query is not working with where statement.

```
string mergeSql = "merge into " + tableName + " as Target " +
                                  "using Ro_Consumers_Temp as Source " +
                                  "on " +
                                  "Target.ContractNo=Source.ContractNo " +
                                  "when not matched then " +
                                  "insert values (Source.Ronumber,Source.ContractNo,Source.BusinessPartner,Source.ContractAccount,Source.IBC,Source.Portion,Source.MRU,Source.Installation,Source.MeterNo,Source.LegacyNumber,Source.ConsumerNo,Source.ConsumerName,Source.Address,Source.Tariff,Source.ROAgent,Source.IBCName,Source.CD,Source.Batch,Source.JasbNumber,Source.SheetNo, Source.ContactName,Source.ContactNumber,Source.FOName,Source.[Address&LandMark],Source.NatureOfBusiness)" +
                                  "when matched then update set Batch = Source.Batch, JasbNumber = Source.JasbNumber Where Target.Batch=Source.Batch;";
```

Comment: You can add a clause to to the `when` like `when not matched and Target.Batch=Source.Batch` instead of having a `where` in the update.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: PLEASE use a parameterized query, for your own good, as this is very likely open to sql injection.

Comment: You could help minimize the risk of sql injection by wrapping tableName in QUOTENAME.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `WHERE` clause with additional `WHEN MATCHED` clause condition:

```
string mergeSql = "merge into " + tableName + " as Target " +
                                  "using Ro_Consumers_Temp as Source " +
                                  "on " +
                                  "Target.ContractNo=Source.ContractNo " +
                                  "when not matched then " +
                                  "insert values (Source.Ronumber,Source.ContractNo,Source.BusinessPartner,Source.ContractAccount,Source.IBC,Source.Portion,Source.MRU,Source.Installation,Source.MeterNo,Source.LegacyNumber,Source.ConsumerNo,Source.ConsumerName,Source.Address,Source.Tariff,Source.ROAgent,Source.IBCName,Source.CD,Source.Batch,Source.JasbNumber,Source.SheetNo, Source.ContactName,Source.ContactNumber,Source.FOName,Source.[Address&LandMark],Source.NatureOfBusiness)" +
                                  "when matched " +
                                  "and Target.Batch=Source.Batch " + // <<< Move the clause here
                                  "then update set Batch = Source.Batch, JasbNumber = Source.JasbNumber";
```

See [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement documentation for more info.